# How to use Spark Classifaction for unseen instances?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

It looks like the training and test set should both be present at the time of classification model creation in Apache Spark? What if we have unseen instances that come later and do not exist when we're creating the model? do we have to re-build the model when we receive an unseen instance? Doesn't it make the classification impractical in real scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like the training and test set should both be present at the time of classification model creation in Apache Spark?

Test instances can be loaded appart from train instances as you can see in [Naive Bayes example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-naive-bayes.html).

```
from pyspark.mllib.classification import NaiveBayes
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

def parseLine(line):
    parts = line.split(',')
    label = float(parts[0])
    features = Vectors.dense([float(x) for x in parts[1].split(' ')])
    return LabeledPoint(label, features)

data = sc.textFile('data/mllib/sample_naive_bayes_data.txt').map(parseLine)

# Split data aproximately into training (60%) and test (40%)
training, test = data.randomSplit([0.6, 0.4], seed = 0)

# Train a naive Bayes model.
model = NaiveBayes.train(training, 1.0)

# Make prediction and test accuracy.
predictionAndLabel = test.map(lambda p : (model.predict(p.features), p.label))
accuracy = 1.0 * predictionAndLabel.filter(lambda (x, v): x == v).count() / test.count()
```

> What if we have unseen instances that come later and do not exist when we're creating the model?

This scenario is the same as with scikit and other machine learning tools, although Spark offers some algorithms that can process streams.

Comment: I didn't quite figure out from you answer, does Spark support classifying new instances or not? If so, how?

Comment: I assume that with an instance you mean a class label. If a model was built without a certain class then you have to rebuild it. You can try this with the example above with seed set to 8000. Trainset will have classes 0 and 2, testset only class 1. So accuracy is 0.

Comment: No, actually what I mean by an instance is a new object to classify, let's say a new document to classify.

Comment: If Naive Bayes gets an unknown instance value in predict phase it omits it.  Unknown instance values in spark's MLlib are treated the same as in other machine learning packages (scikit, Orange, Knime, etc.).

Comment: No, I'm not talking about an unknown instance. I'm talking about a new instance, an instance which didn't exist in the training phase and is given to the classifier later.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand why both training and testing have to be present at the same time "of classification model creation in Apache Spark". The whole idea of splitting between training and testing is that you use training for building the model and keep testing separated so you can then use it to test your predictions, by evaluating it in "unseen" data.

For example, when you split your data you do something like:

```
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))
```

Then when you train your model lets say a classifier for ex Logistic Regression you only pass trainingData to it, it is not aware of the existence of any testData when it is trained.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.{LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel}
val modelLR = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().run(trainingData)
```

Then you can test your results in testData like:

```
val testing = testData.map { point =>
  val prediction = modelLR.predict(point.features)
  (point.label, prediction)
}
```

Here evaluating the model only needs a vector of features specified in `val prediction = modelLR.predict(point.features)`. The point.label is used for calculating performance metrics like accuracy, precision etc etc.

If you are thinking about how to put this model built into production where new unseen instances need prediction you only need to create a LabeledPoint vector with the same features as your model was trained with, and it will return a prediction result.

I hope this helps